# How to retrieve multiple values from database and set it as variable

Tags: mysql, perl

**Inside table(1)**

```
ID      Name      Address        Phone       InsertDate

1      Andrew     12-A,ABC      576849203    2014/05/06
1      Andrew     12-A,ABC      123456789    2014/07/08
```

**Inside table(2)**

```
ID      Name      Address        Phone       InsertDate

1      Andrew     12-A,ABC       123456789    2014/07/08
```

The problem I met is when I `Select * from table(1) where id='1'`. It will retrieve two records. Then when I try to insert to `table(2)`. It only show one record in table(2) instead of 2 records.

What should I do so I can get the two records from table(1) and insert to table(2)?

My example Code:

```
$mysql="Select * from table(1) where id='1'";
**Perform the query**

**Retrieve values**
$sth->bind_col(1, \$Name);
$sth->bind_col(2, \$Address);
$sth->bind_col(3, \$Phone);
$sth->bind_col(4, \$InsertDate);

if($sth->fetch()){
  $mysql="Insert into table(2) values($Name,$Address,$Phone,InsertDate)";
  **Perform the query**
}
```

Thanks for viewing,comments and answers!

Comment: `if($sth->fetch())` => `while($sth->fetch())`, and use placeholders to fetch and insert. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `SELECT * FROM table(1)` so you are fetching *all* of the columns. The first is `ID` so your column binding is incorrect, and it is hard to believe that your code copies even one record correctly. In addition, you are executing `fetch` only once, so you are only ever trying to insert one of the two rows into `table(2)`.

You need to write something like this

```
my $read = $dbh->prepare(<<'__END_SQL__');
SELECT Name, Address, Phone, InsertDate
FROM table(1)
WHERE ID = ?
__END_SQL__

my $write = $dbh->prepare(<<'__END_SQL__');
INSERT INTO table(2) (Name, Address, Phone, InsertDate)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
__END_SQL__

$read->execute(1);

while (my $row = $read->fetchrow_arrayref) {
  $write->execute(@$row);
}
```

But, unless there is a reason why you want access at the Perl level to the records being copied, you could let the database do all of it for you, like this

```
my copy = $dbh->prepare(<<'__END_SQL__');
INSERT INTO table(2) (Name, Address, Phone, InsertDate)
  SELECT Name, Address, Phone, InsertDate
  FROM table(1)
  WHERE ID = ?
__END_SQL__

$copy->execute(1);
```

Comment: I like your heredoc style for SQL statements.  I realize it's close to what's recommended by Conway, but I'm bookmarking for future reference anyway. +1

Answer (score -1):

first of all make sure in table2 , id or name or some other field is not set to primary or it will not allow u insert duplicate records ..

try this PHP code...

```
result=mysql_query(" select * from table where id=1 ");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$name=$row["Name"];
$address==$row["address"];
$phone==$row["phone"];
$insertdate=$row["insertdate"];

mysql_query( "insert into table2(name,address,phone,insertdate) values('$name','$address','$phone','$insertdate') ");

}
```

Comment: But ... this is a Perl question

Comment: thanks, i actually thought the problem is with the primary keys gave php for a reference but agree dat its a mistake ....